# STM32 C++ operator new (CoIDE)

Tags: c++, gcc, embedded, stm32, newlib

I'm new in ARM programming, I'm using CoIDE, I'm trying to write some application to read PWM from 8 channels, in C++.

My problem is using operator `new`; if I write:

```
RxPort rxPort = RxPort(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOA, GPIOA, GPIO_Pin_6, GPIO_PinSource6, GPIO_AF_TIM3, RCC_APB1Periph_TIM3, TIM3, TIM_Channel_1, TIM_IT_CC1, TIM3_IRQn);
```

it works fine, but if I write:

```
RxPort* rxPort1 = new RxPort;
rxPort1->setTimerParameters(RCC_APB1Periph_TIM3, TIM3, TIM_Channel_1, TIM_IT_CC1, TIM3_IRQn);
rxPort1->setGPIOParameters(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOA, GPIOA, GPIO_Pin_6, GPIO_PinSource6, GPIO_AF_TIM3);
rxPort1->init();
```

program goes to:

```
static void Default_Handler(void)
{
    /* Go into an infinite loop. */
    while (1)
    {
    }
}
```

after first line.

I've found one topic on my.st.com [here](https://my.st.com/public/STe2ecommunities/mcu/Lists/cortex_mx_stm32/Flat.aspx?RootFolder=/public/STe2ecommunities/mcu/Lists/cortex_mx_stm32/Memory%20overflow%20by%20using%20C%2b%2b%20operator%20new&FolderCTID=0x01200200770978C69A1141439FE559EB459D7580009C4E14902C3CDE46A77F0FFD06506F5B&currentviews=114), and tried to add "--specs=nano.specs" to "Misc Controls" in "Link" and "Compile" section, but nothing changes.

Comment: Usually there might be no appropriate implementation for `new()` with such a small and RAM limited device. Don't know about the IDE you mentioned, but you should investigate how your actual toolchain is configured. When you get to `Default_Handler()` this means you're stuck on some 'exception'. Do you use an RTOS, if yes which one?

Comment: @g-makulik, no, I don't. May you help me to find another way? Is it global variables or configuring all in 'void main' because I can't fill array with objects in constructor, because objects will destroyed when procedure ends.

Comment: What's your (cross) toolchain? GCC? (Sorry I don't know what `--specs=nano.specs` will mean with your IDE/Toolchain)

Comment: @g-makulik it's GNU Tools ARM Embedded arm-none-eabi-gdb

Comment: I'd guess the provided newlib/glibc-stubs don't support `malloc`/`free`

Comment: `arm-none-eabi-gdb` is just the debugger application BTW. Do you build the toolchain yourself, or do you use a preconfigured one?

Comment: @g-makulik, thanks, I'll change type of array from pointer to object and fill it in `void main()`.

Comment: just downloaded it from official site. Yep, it's gcc

Comment: In short: Just avoid uses of `new()` in your implementations, because it's apparently not supported for your environment.

Comment: See this blog post for an example of how your could implement the newlib malloc stub: http://michaldemin.wordpress.com/2010/03/09/freertos-newlib-on-cortex-m3/

Answer (score 3):

To support new/delete and malloc/free in GCC with then newlib C library, you must implement the `_sbrk_r()` syscalls stub, and allocate an area of memory for the heap.  Typically the latter is done via the linker script, but you can also simply allocate a large static array.  A smart linker script however can be written so that the heap automatically uses all available memory after static object and system stack allocation.

An example `sbrk_r()` implementation (as well as the other syscall stubs for supporting library features such as stream I/O) can be found on [Bill Gatliff's site](http://www.billgatliff.com/newlib.html).  If you are using CoOS or any other multitasking OS or executive, and are intending to allocate from multiple threads you will also need to implement `__malloc_lock()` and `__malloc_unlock()` too.

Your code ended up in `Default_Handler` because `new` is required to throw an exception when it fails and you had no explicit `try`/`catch` block.  If you would rather have `malloc()` style semantics and simply return null on failure, you can use the [`new (std::nothrow)`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/nothrow/).

Answer (score 1):

Apparently your active GCC toolchain newlib stubs don't support use of low level dynamic memory allocation (`malloc()`,`free()`, etc.). The usage of `new()` or `delete()` for C++ bindings might raise a default 'exception' handler at run time.

The details depend on the newlib stubs provided with your configuration. Note that you can override the stub functions with your own implementations.

You'll find some useful additional hints in this article: [Building GCC 4.7.1 ARM cross toolchain on Suse 12.2](http://dev-jungle.blogspot.de/2013/09/building-gcc-471-arm-cross-toolchain-on.html)